# How to Use Expand Controls in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Control implement in UWP Apps ,now i m trying to do expand controls Universal Windows Apps ,but i did't get properly to expandable contain ,so how to get expand control in UWP Technology ?

Comment: Yes, but My recruitment is when i click first automatic expand All Contain ,

Comment: Yes, but My recruitment is when i click first automatic expand All Contain , Executly i have Design ListView in Listview i have add more  Listviewitem ,so First ListViewitem I have no of contain and i want to add first Listviewitem all contain and when i click first Listviewitem  Automatic Expand All Contains .

Comment: One more Recruitment Have When design All Contain it should not display  Navigate Icon or Arrow Mark it  should Display Only Contain ?